# Scala: クラス定義を追加すると、scala コマンドで main メソッドが実行されなくなる

Tags: scala

scala コマンドで *.scala ファイルをスクリプトのように実行する場合の、
クラス定義の書き方について質問させてください。

```
// a.scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hello")
  }
}
```

上の a.scala ファイルを scala コマンドで実行すると、main メソッドが呼び出されて
hello と表示されます。

```
$ scala a.scala
hello
```

次に a.scala にクラス Foo の定義を追加すると、今度は main メソッドが呼び出されなくなります。

```
// a.scala
class Foo {} // クラス定義を追加する

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hello")
  }
}
```

scala コマンドで実行してみると、main メソッドが呼ばれなくなりました。

```
$ scala a.scala
$ # 何も表示されない
```

以下の方法ですと、main メソッドが実行されることは確認しています。

- scalac コマンドでコンパイルしてから、scala Main を実行
- クラス Foo の定義を、Main の中で定義する

質問なのですが、Main の外でクラス Foo を定義して、
scala a.scala で main メソッドを呼ぶ方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 方法1

`scalac`でコンパイルして実行する
http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html#compile-it

```
> scalac a.scala
> ls

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2016/01/01     14:13            122 a.scala
-a----       2016/01/01     14:13            474 Foo.class
-a----       2016/01/01     14:13            608 Main$.class
-a----       2016/01/01     14:13            546 Main.class

> scala Main
hello
```

### 方法2

`scala`コマンドはコードをスクリプトとして実行します。
そしてコードがmainメソッドのあるclassまたはobjectだけの場合は、mainメソッドを自動で実行してくれます。

**類似の質問への回答**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993075/4366193

今回のようなコードでは`object Main`と`class Foo`の定義のみでスクリプトが終了し、mainメソッドは自動で実行されません。
BLUEPIXYさんの回答のように明示的に`Main.main(args)`を呼び出せば実行されます。

```scala
class Foo {}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hello")
  }
}

Main.main(args)
```

### 方法3

方法2をふまえると`object Main`だけがトップレベルで定義されていればmainメソッドが自動で実行されますので、`object Main`内に`class Foo`を定義する方法があります。

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Foo.hello()
  }

  class Foo

  object Foo {
    def hello(): Unit = {
      println("hello")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ソースコードを変更したくない場合は、以下の様にすると良いかと思います。

```
$ scala -i a.scala -e 'Main.main(args)'
```

その他には sbt を使う方法もあります。

```
$ sbt 'run-main Main'
```

Answer (score 1):

最後に
`Main.main(args)`
を追加して書いて明示的に呼び出す。